# Where To Buy A Garlic Crusher?

Tags: garlic

Sorry for taking up your time. Just wondering if anyone knows where i can buy a garlic crusher from?

I want to cook some Italian food, but every Thai person i ask has no idea what a garlic crusher is. I looked at Hicorfe, any other place i can try?

**This is my friend's garlic press. Any ideas or suggestions?**

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Any kitchen store? amazon? Look for "garlic press".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question, therefore localized and with a limited shelf life.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is cook Italian food and you want to use fresh garlic, crushing the garlic with the flat of a knife and then mincing it finely will get you through the night without a special shopping trip.

Nearly any store that sells kitchen accessories should have multiple *garlic presses* to choose from. Knowing the country in which you reside could help, but examples include all of the following options.

**Kitchen Supply Stores**

- Happy Kitchen (physical)
- Cook's Direct (online)

**General-Purpose Stores**

- Amazon (online)
- EBay (online)
- Target (physical & online)

**Grocery Stores** often have overpriced kitchen accessories as a convenience to their shoppers, garlic presses included.

- Safeway (physical)
- Whole Foods (physical)

Comment: This makes a big assumption that isn't justified by the question: There are strong  hints that the OP isn't in the US (as all your offline and 1/3 of your online sources are) and nothing to suggest they are in the US.